# UWP and a List of Serial Devices

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Universal Windows Platform uses the following namespace to look at COM and or USB Ports for connected devices: SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector

This give me a single devices, I would like to get a list of all ports and devices attached.

Is there an ability get a List of devices already connected? 
For example:

```
 foreach(var item in SerialDevice.List) 
 {
       var name = item.Name
 }
```

The goal would be to obtain all the USB devices attached.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice#methods)

> Gets an Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) string that the app can pass to [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync#Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation_FindAllAsync_System_String_) in order to find all serial devices on the system

So, you could get all device with the following code.

```
var list = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```